# Inspect doesn't recognize win32 editable textbox

Tags: c++, winapi, edit, inspect

I developed a win32 application (c++) and now, I want to do some automation tests using Inspect (SDK).

My problem is that Inspect doesn't recognize `EDIT` boxes. I mean that Inspect can't distinguish their names. It can see that there are multiple `EDIT` boxes, but they're all named "none" which occur to be the null value. Those names are always null, even if I initialize them with the `LPCTSTR lpWindowName` parameter

```
// Create an edit box
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        _T("EDIT"),
        _T("I JUST WANT TO BE SEEN !"),
        WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
        ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        50,
        100,
        200,
        100,
        hWnd,
        (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL);
```

I also try setting the name with the `setWindowText` method, but it doesn't work either.
The two method does work fine with `BUTTON`, but doesn't work on `EDIT`.

Does anyone as a clue?

Comment: Are you sure your window text doesn't show up anywhere in the accessible object? Is it not `accValue`? If it is `accValue` I think I have a feeling of what's going on...

Comment: It can't distinguish them by ID? E.g. in your example above, the ID is `IDC_MAIN_EDIT`.

Comment: In fact, the `LPCTSTR lpWindowName` show up has the text in the edit box. So yes, @andlabs, it's the current value instead of name.

Comment: @andlabs: In fact, the LPCTSTR lpWindowName show up has the text in the edit box. So yes, it's the current value instead of the name. (sorry for the repost)

Comment: Yes, the Window Text of an edit control is the text that has been entered. My question to you is is that what shows up in the Inspect tool as "Value:"? If so, I could provide a hypothesis as to what's going on. If you want to try where I'm going with this, place a label to the left of one of the edit boxes with some other text, and then get the accessibility information for that edit box.

Comment: @andlabs: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, but does the `lpWindowName` suppose to be the name of the control? I think I found how to solve my problem, but I would like to understand why is `lpWindowName`  show as the default text?

Comment: The `lpWindowName` parameter to `CreateWindwEx()` has no relation to the "accessible name". A more appropriate name for the parameter would be `lpWindowText`. I'm guessing the parameter calls it a "name" because they intended title bar captions to be called such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set the name (or any other property of the control) by using Dynamic Annotation.
Also, if it's a common control, it might be possible to set the name by adding a hidden label in the .rc file. Otherwise you'll have to use Dynamic Annotation.

if you want to set one of these :

```
-NAME                  -KEYBOARDSHORTCUT
-DESCRIPTION           -DEFAULTACTION
-ROLE                  -VALUEMAP
-STATE                 -ROLEMAP
-HELP                  -STATEMAP.
```

You'll have to use Direct Annotation or Server Annotation.
But if you want to set one of these :

```
-FOCUS                 -RIGHT
-SELECTION             -PREV
-PARENT                -NEXT
-UP                    -FIRSTCHILD
-DOWN                  -LASTCHILD
-LEFT
```

Only the Server Annotation will allow you to do it.

Here's more detail about Dynamic Annotation :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gg712214.aspx

Here's more detail if you want to do Dynamic Annotation on custom control :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cc307845.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is where I was heading with my questions. See my comment above about the misleading parameter names.